# VB.Net Data Grid View

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I am getting problems with my code. It's saying in the error that I should put a `New` in the code but i don't know where to put it. This is the complete code for the function:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim TA As New POSCanteenTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter
        Dim TB = TA.GetDataByBarcode(TextBox1.Text)
        If TB.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Dim IR As POSCanteen.ItemsRow = TB.Rows(0)
        TextBox2.Text = IR.ItemName
        TextBox3.Text = IR.SellPrice
        Button2.Tag = IR
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim IR As POSCanteen.ItemsRow = Button1.Tag
    Dim RI As New Integer
    Dim ItemLoc As Integer = -1
    For RI = 0 To CDGV3.Rows.Count - 1
        If IR.Barcode = CDGV3.Rows(RI).Cells(0).Value Then
            ItemLoc = RI
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If ItemLoc = -1 Then
        CDGV3.Rows.Add(IR.Barcode, IR.ItemName, IR.BuyPrice, IR.SellPrice, 1, IR.SellPrice)
    Else
        Dim ItemCount As Long = CDGV3.Rows(ItemLoc).Cells(4).Value
        ItemCount += 1
        Dim NewPrice As Decimal = IR.SellPrice * ItemCount
        CDGV3.Rows(ItemLoc).Cells(4).Value = ItemCount
        CDGV3.Rows(ItemLoc).Cells(5).Value = NewPrice
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

It is supposed to add an item in the Data Grid but it won't because of that error. I don't know where to put it since the compiler doesn't tell me where.

This is the exception message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: WHERE does it give the error?  VS will tell you exactly which thing is NOTHING just using the mouse.

Comment: On the part on CDGV3.rows.add(IR.ItemName.IR.BuyPrice,Ir.SellPrice,1,Ir.Sellprice)

Comment: With the mouse over the `IR` variable is it `Nothing`?

Comment: turn on `OPTION STRICT` to see whats wrong

Comment: where is that option ??

Comment: just type `option Strict` at the top of the module

Comment: turned it on ! and said System.nullReferrenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object):(

Answer (score 1):

You need to think ahead for the possibility that an object does not convert(esp when you let the compiler guess). Not sure if that is the object causing the problem, but you may know. Learn how to step through the code with the debugger.

```
Dim IR = TryCast(Button1.Tag, {type})
If Not IR Is Nothing Then
  'rest of your code
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your line so i'm suggesting this.

Try any of this

```
Dim IR As New POSCanteen.ItemsRow = Button1.Tag

Dim ItemCount As New Long = CDGV3.Rows(ItemLoc).Cells(4).Value

Dim NewPrice As New Decimal = IR.SellPrice * ItemCount
```

Comment: I already tried that ! but its produce more errors ! :D! the function is for Button ! :D!

Comment: i put all the codes ! 
im getting exception on the part in CDGV3.Rows.add(IR.Barcode,IR.ItemName,IR.BuyPrice,IR.SellPrice,1,IR.SellPrice)

Comment: I hope that your problem is in creating Object IR.. So take a look on it